# Undefined local variable or method for a Hash for main:Object (NameError)

Tags: ruby, hash

So I have a hash called pushups that I defined outside another method I created:

```
pushups = {"2015-04-16-10:05:01" => 25, "2015-04-10-10:05:01" => 150, "2015-04-11-10:05:01" => 99 }
```

However, when I run the method below on the hash above I get the following error:

**undefined local variable or method `pushups' for main:Object (NameError)**

Basically, I just want to convert all the keys in the hash above and print it out in an updated hash with the same values or even just as a new array of all the updated keys.

```
 def convert_dates(timestamp)

     pushups.each do |timestamp, numberOfPushups|
     date = DateTime.strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S")
     end

     print date

 end
```

I thought I adequately defined and initialized the hash.  So I'm not really sure if that is the problem or not. What seems to be wrong here?

Comment: Why would you get an error for `pushups` when variable in code is `pullups`?  Are you copy-pasting error or entering it manually here?  Pls share correct message.

Comment: Sorry for the typo!  I fixed it.

Comment: If you just want to print the dates: `require 'date'; p pushups.map { |timestamp,_| DateTime.strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S") }`. Your code  is loaded with errors. I'm sorry, but I don't have the time now to go through it. Perhaps someone else could post an answer that identifies the errors and shows you how to fix them. Don't be too dismayed, most of us had similar problems when we were first learning Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to use closures, then, function defined using `def` does not support closure behavior - it does not remember the variables bound outside its definition.

In your case, you can change variable `pushups` to `@pushups` to make it instance variable.

Alternatively you may have to use lambda or equivalent.  A simplified example is shown below that shows how you can access `pushups` within a lambda.

**Sample code**

```
pushups = {"2015-04-16-10:05:01" => 25, "2015-04-10-10:05:01" => 150, "2015-04-11-10:05:01" => 99 }

l = ->(timestamp) do 
    p pushups 
end

l.call ("2015-04-16-10:05:01")
```

**Output**

```
{"2015-04-16-10:05:01"=>25, "2015-04-10-10:05:01"=>150, "2015-04-11-10:05:01"=>99}
```

Reference: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/180579/what-is-a-closure-and-how-is-it-implemented-in-ruby

Comment: I still get "undefined local variable or method `timestamp' for main:Object (NameError)" when I run the above code with the same process I had above but using this lambda.